# How to extract version information of the dependencies

Tags: angular, typescript

I was wondering is there a way to extract and print version information of all dependencies? 
For example I am using following dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.15",
    "bu-controls": "^0.0.34",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "jquery": "^2.2.0",
    "moment": "2.14.1",
    "ms-signalr-client": "2.2.5",
    "ng2-translate": "^1.11.1",
    "numeral": "1.5.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",
    "systemjs": "~0.19.18",
    "underscore": "1.8.3",
    "zone.js": "0.6.10"
  }
```

So my task is to display version information on the browser for the clients.
Thank you very much, in advance, for your help.

Comment: Is it going to need to be on demand? As in the user clicks a button and then the dependencies show up?

Comment: I am going to have a page, there all the dependencies will be displayed in a table.

Comment: just deploy json with dependencies and use it

Comment: Thanks Aleksey, wanted to avoid deploying package.json, if you meant that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you're using npm, you can redirect the output of the command `npm list --depth=0` to a file, and then parse the file and display the contents on your webpage in the browser.

Here's an example of what `npm list --depth=0` looks like in a project of mine.

```
+-- @angular/common@2.0.0-rc.5
+-- @angular/compiler@2.0.0-rc.5
+-- @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.5
+-- @angular/forms@0.3.0
+-- @angular/http@2.0.0-rc.5
+-- @angular/platform-browser@2.0.0-rc.5
+-- @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.0.0-rc.5
+-- @angular/router@3.0.0-rc.1
+-- @angular/router-deprecated@2.0.0-rc.2
+-- @angular/upgrade@2.0.0-rc.5
+-- angular2-in-memory-web-api@0.0.15
+-- bootstrap@3.3.7
+-- concurrently@2.2.0
+-- core-js@2.4.1
+-- lite-server@2.2.2
+-- reflect-metadata@0.1.8 invalid
+-- rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6
+-- systemjs@0.19.27
+-- typescript@1.8.10
+-- typings@1.3.2
`-- zone.js@0.6.12
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, in this way will I always depend on updating the list file (file created after npm list --depth=0)? I mean, if version of some lib has been changes, to display it the list file has to be updated.

Comment: Yes that would be correct, any time you updated any dependencies the file would have to be updated to match the new version. This could be mitigated by making a new file every time a user goes to this dependency page, though I'm not sure if that's something that you'd want or be willing to do.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will add a script that is triggered each time when `npm install` is run. This way I hope to update the list file each time when `npm i` is run.